# Google Maps API: Automatic Batch Markers

Tags: google-maps

If I bring up google maps in my browser, and type "Museums near Toronto, ON, Canada", I get a map of Toronto with a bunch of markers for museums.

So if I build a web page and program it to display a map in it with google maps API, is there a way to tell the google maps API to display markers for all museums in the map I'm displaying? Because the data is clearly there, and to have to manually create the markers from scratch would be a daunting task.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to request a "*show markers for all museum's* ", but you may get the the data about museums by requesting a place search.

You'll find the Manual here: http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html

A request for e.g.:

```
{
  location: new google.maps.LatLng(43.653226, -79.38318429999998),//Toronto
  radius: 10000,
  types: ['museum']
}
```

...will give you a bunch of data about museum's in Toronto, but you have to create the markers on your own by using that data.

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/WcxYa/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/WcxYa/)

Comment: Thanks very much! I looked at the demo and copied the code and got it working on my server. Something very odd: when I tried it on Toronto and New York, it worked. But when I tried it on a few cities east of the Atlantic, nada. Any clues on this?

Comment: This may be interesting to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477512/google-places-api-not-returning-any-results-for-india/9480019#9480019