# Google Places API not returning any results for India

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=28.635704,77.224982&radius=50000&types=restaurant&language=en&name=&sensor=false&key=[key]

I have been trying to find Google Places API 3 to get the list of restaurants in Delhi, but so far I have not got any luck. Has anyone tried that before. It shows good results with coordinates in US but nothing in Delhi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is the categorization applied by the owners of the places.  When I search for "restaurant delhi" on google-maps I get a lot of restaurants, but none of them is categorized as "restaurant", it's lodging, restaurants-indian,Restaurants - Non - Vegetarian or something else, but never **restaurant** .

Instead of requesting the **types** *restaurant* search for the **name** *restaurant* , you'll get a bunch of results.

When you take a look at these results, you'll see, the **types** of the most results is set to "establishment" , not "restaurant"

Comment: You can also set `keyword=restaurant` - keyword is "A term to be matched against all available fields, including but not limited to name, type, and address, as well as customer reviews and other third-party content."