# Google API not working with other latitude and longitude

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I want to use google API in my project.
The api i got is from [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#Authentication)

And the APi IS :- https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=5000&types=food&sensor=false&key=***********************************

**NOTE**:- I had appended my KEY at the end of this URL. It is showing me proper response.
But if i change the latitude and longitude to Gujarat state ( country india) ..Then it is not showing me any response.
And the response if ZERO_RESULT

Can anyone help me why it is happening and how to solve it.

I This is want to do this is to get the nearby information of current latitide-longitude.. 
Is there any other way or api to get the information of nearby area..
Please help me..
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please could you provide the latitude and longitude to Gujarat state that you are using?

Comment: The latitude and longitude of gujarat, Ahmedabad which i m using is Latitude=23.00 and longitude=72.00

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Places API not returning any results for India](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477512/google-places-api-not-returning-any-results-for-india)

Comment: @Dr.Molle thanks for the reply.I get the solution.But is there any way to get the image of the category .As the place API is only giving the icon of the particular place..

Comment: Inside the response may be listed an icon-url for the place. When you like to use own markers, you may create them on your own, by using own images(or use the sprites of google, e.g. http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/de_ALL/mapfiles/ms2/iconm.png )

Comment: The default food icon is here: [http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png](http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png)

Comment: @ChrisGreen thanx for the reply..I Dont want the to display the icon of the perticualar category..The thing we want to display is the image of category..

Comment: @sweta i dont understand what you mean by image of a category. Do you mean an image of the place like what is displayed on a Google Maps Place Page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this snippet and it works for every case.

```
<body>
<div id="mainpanel" style="float:left; background-color:#fff; width:75%;">
    <div style="display:none;" id="lat">hhh</div><div style="display:none;" id="lon">hhh</div>


<script>
var x=document.getElementById("lat");
var y=document.getElementById("lon");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
  x.innerHTML=position.coords.latitude; 
  y.innerHTML=position.coords.longitude;
  loadScript();
  }

function initialize()
{
var xval=document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML;
var yval=document.getElementById("lon").innerHTML;
var mapProp = {
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(xval,yval),
    zoom:7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}

function loadScript()
{
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
//window.onload = loadScript;
</script>
    <form>
        <input class="boxinput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" id="" name=""/>
        </form>
    <div class="serchbox"></div>
    <div id="googleMap" style="width:960px;height:804px;"></div>

    </div>  
     </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no register place on map around given coordinates(latitude & longitude) with given radius then API will responds ZERO_RESULT

To get result

- Specify correct coordinates(Current location)
- Radius limit, maximum allowed radius is 50000 meters = 50 KM

Following url is working - Gives places of type food within 30 KM distance from Gujarat (given coordinates).

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=23.0,72.0&radius=30000&types=food&sensor=false&key= [API key]